# HttpClient is returning Internal Server Error (500) on API controller with constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient

I am doing an Api Controller Application.

On My Api Method I want to call a Function defined in another Project. I want to use IOC. I define an Interface and a Class that inherit from interface.

The problem I have when I call the Controller/Method is that I have error  `Internal Server Error (500)`

I test every posibility, and it occurs because I use a Controller Constructor. If I avoid using it, is Works.

It does not work,

```html
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
private IUserLogin _userLogin;

        public LoginController(IUserLogin userLogin)
        {
              _userLogin = userLogin;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public UserToken Login([FromBody]Users user)
        {
               return _userLogin.SetToken(user);
            
        }
}
```

It Works without Constructor

```html
  public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public UserToken Login([FromBody]Users user)
        {
             private IUserLogin _userLogin;
                return _userLogin.SetToken(user);
        }
     }
```

It Works...

I am doing my call from WinForm like this

```html
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //reference nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl + "Login/Login", user).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    userToken = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserToken>().Result;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Error");
            }
```

How can I use Controller Constructor and Not get any error?

Comment: You need to figure out what the error is. Implement logging etc.

Comment: Based on this doc, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection in the `constructor injection` part, your code looks fine...I think that maybe the way that you are calling your other project is the issue...can you give us a little more background about it.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to see detailed error message inside raw headers sent/received by clicking on the errored request, and check parameters being sent out.

Comment: It almost sounds as if you aren't registering your **IUserLogin** interface under your dependency container.  Chances are the error is due to  WebAPI looking for a parameterless constructor that is no longer present. You'd need to provide how you are registering your dependencies.